# Energy of a wave

Tags: waves

Energy density of a wave is given by $$E=\rho\omega^2A^2\cos^2(kx-\omega(t))$$.However for purposes of calculation we use the average of energy.i.e $$E=\frac{\rho\omega^2A^2}{2}$$
WHY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least two reasons:

1. The instantaneous energy density tells you nothing about the total energy content of the wave, so it's of little utility.
2. Experiments measure the average energy.

Comment: Did not expect such an easy answer

Answer (score 1):

Energy of a wave is an oscillating quantity. Higher the frequency of the wave the more difficult it becomes to measure the energy instantaneously. Imagine sending an alternating current through a direct current ammeter. The ammeter wouldn't know how to respond. But if the same current is sent to an ac ammeter it reads the root **mean** square value of the current which is a form of an average. The instantaneous value of the alternating current can never be measured.